# How to run setup code before extension loaded in puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I am testing the behavior of a chrome extension using puppeteer.
Upon installation, the extension opens a page. I would like to do initial setup in the browser before the extension is loaded (for example, setting local storage or injecting a jest mock).

The problem I have now is that the extension gets loaded upon browser start, so I don't know of any way to execute setup code before the extension is loaded.

This is how I load the extension currently (which resides in the `dist/chrome` folder):

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--disable-extensions-except=dist/chrome',
      '--load-extension=dist/chrome',
    ],
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
  });
```

How can I do initial setup before the extension is loaded?

Some options I can think of are: 1) load the extension *after* the browser is launched 2) intercept the extension installation and execute setup code before the extension initializes

Answer (score 0):

I came searching for an answer and I found it reading your question, so I'm leaving it here in case I have to search for it again in the future ...

The trick is to create a "launcher" extension with the sole purpose running the setup code, before the actual extension is ran. It would look like:

```
      '--disable-extensions-except=dist/launcher,dist/chrome',
      '--load-extension=dist/launcher,dist/chrome',
```